# how to prevent duplication. Java,SQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I try duplicate the entries in the `username` column but the result is always in the `else` statement which is the data is successfully inserted into the table which should not be duplicated based on the `if` statement. By the way `String value1=username1.getText();`.

here's the code:

```
String sq = "SELECT username FROM login where username = '"+value1+"'";

if (sq.equals(value1)){ 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"username is already existed! please 
create new username.");   
}
else{
int k=st.executeUpdate("insert into 
login(username,password,firstname,lastname,address,contactno) 


values('"+value1+"','"+value2+"','"+value3+"','"+value4+"',
'"+value5+"','"+value6+"')");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is successfully saved");
}
```

Comment: have you debbuged and checked values of two strings are equal or not?

Comment: Well you never actually execute the `SELECT username` query.  How can you get the result set without running the query?

Comment: @shinbona as far as I understand after looking your code you haven't executed your "sq" query. You have to compare the result returned by executing sq

Comment: Best way to avoid duplications is to add a UNIQUE key on username within the database...first selecting and checking is prone to race conditions...

Comment: Added to others comments don't use `Statement` use `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 2):

You just create the SQL string and never run it (instead, you compare it to the username, which will always be false).

You should actually execute it and check the result.
E.g. (error handling and resource cleanup omitted for brevity's sake):

```
Connection conn = // Connect to the database... 
PreparedStatement ps = 
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM login where username = ?";
ps.setString(1, value1);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (null,"username is already existed! please create new username.");   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

sq will never be equal to value1 if you just assign it to a complete SELECT statement:

```
String sq = "SELECT username FROM login where username = '"+value1+"'";
```

What you are missing is the DB request for your sq String.

Answer (score 0):

`sq` contains the query (sql code)

```
String sq = "SELECT username FROM login where username = '"+value1+"'";
```

`value1` contains the username value (for example "user1"). So

```
sq.equals(value1)
```

will be always false

```
"SELECT username FROM login where username = '"+value1+"'" != value1
```

Answer (score 0):

**String Basics:**

```
String sq = "Something in double quotes"
```

Assigns `Something` to sq.

And

```
String value1=username1.getText();
```

May get some other string, lets say for example "root"

```
sq.equals(value1)
```

Now String class `equals()` method check content of both Strings(sq and value1).

And if not equal returns false, which happens in your case.

Now how to achieve your goal? people already answered that check it.

I recommend to [study](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) yourself