# Avoid SQL duplication in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Im trying to avoid SQL duplication. I found this code here [how to prevent duplication. Java,SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582390/how-to-prevent-duplication-java-sql) which is successful. I know `rs.next` will move the cursor, but how does it help avoid duplication (does it compare every value)? What is done is just checking is there another row and if there return true right?

```
Connection conn = // Connect to the database... 
PreparedStatement ps = 
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM login where username = ?";
ps.setString(1, value1);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (null,"username is already existed! please create new username.");   
}
```

Comment: *I know rs.nextwill move cursor but how it helps avoid duplication(dose it compare every value).* It has no action in avoiding duplication. For instance it might find several rows have that value. It's the *code* that checks for duplication by finding out if there is *at least one* user with that name already in the table. That's why it only has to move the cursor *once*

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL duplication"?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i'm sorry for my the bad English.I meant to avoid adding duplicate data to SQL table

Comment: The appropriate solution is to use a unique constraint on the table, execute the insert and handle the exception if the constraint is violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite straightforward. You make a query that fetches ALL rows of the table `login` where `username = XXX`. Then you check whether there is any data in the `ResultSet` by executing the `rs.next()` function. This function returns a `boolean` value that is `true` when there is yet more data in the `rs` and `false` when there is no more data.

As you said, it also moves the cursor.

> Does it compare every value(row)?

Yes. Your query looks every row up and checks whether `username = XXX`